# Methods for streaming data real-time from cloud to .NET application?

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, signalr, comet, polling

I am seeking a list of solutions with details/starting point for implementing streaming data from a web server to a client .NET application.  In particular, how do cloud services like SQS and SNS differ from SignalR and polling/or with custom solution?

I have identified the technologies. I am seeking a description that shares how these technologies are specifically related and where they fit in:

- SignalR
- Polling
- COMET
- Web Sockets
- Cloud Services such as  http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/ and http://aws.amazon.com/sns/ and  http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/
- MsgConnect

Answer (score 2):

This categorization would help:

1. the underlying mechanics: push vs. pull (poll):

   1. push: usually implemented using an open socket: raw tcp, websocket (for HTML5 clients).
   2. polling: client query the server every interval
   3. long polling: like polling, but server keeps the request open and responds on new event
2. generic concepts / buzzword

   1. Comet
3. language / framework / technology

   1. .Net - signalIR
   2. nodejs - socketIO (multi technologies used, but intended mainly for web clients)
   3. python - twisted, tornado (generic frameworks)
   4. Queueing technologies: RabbitMQ, AMQP, 0MQ - all with multiple language bindings
   5. XMPP (standard / protocol) - multiple server implementations with multiple language bindings
4. Self hosted vs. managed service

   1. you host the 'push' server implemented using one of the above frameworks
   2. someone else is hosting the service and providing the server api and the client libraries:
   3. pubnub
   4. pusher
   5. MS Azure : service bus , notification bus
   6. AWS SQS - managed queue (where the clients poll/long poll), SNS - multiple formats mostly not relevant for your use case (maybe except webhooks)

Other things to check / compare :

1. Latency - very different between the technologies
2. Message throughput
3. Scalability model

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to answer my own question here. Please expand/make corrections and clarifications where possible.

Comet -> A model for pushing data to clients over HTTP. Comet is an umbrella term that encompasses multiple technologies.

Polling -> A method for retrieving data over HTTP by making repeated requests

Web Sockets -> A new technology part of HTMl5 that supercedes COMET. Support is limited?

Cloud Services -> A "hosted" solution for message delivery and notification. These services may use 
Comet, Polling, or Web Sockets depending on what is available.

MsgConnect and SignalR -> These are self hosted solutions/technologies for transferring data over 
HTTP and may use Comet technologies and/or web Web Sockets. SignalR is primarily a .NET technology designed for implementing streaming over the web.

SignalR can use Comet technologies or polling and/or possibly be deployed over cloud. They are just methods for transfer and don't include server services such as the cloud services

The Cloud services differ from technologies such as SignalR in that they include APIs for transferring data, databases for hosting the data, and an available service address that clients can connect too whereas SignalR would be deployed on a web server/server that one manages/own.

Please see the following for additional information:

What is ASP.NET SignalR
ASP.NET SignalR is a new library for ASP.NET developers that makes it incredibly simple to add real-time web functionality to your applications. What is "real-time web" functionality? It's the ability to have your server-side code push content to the connected clients as it happens, in real-time.

http://www.asp.net/signalr

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-signalr-self-host

Comet is a web application model in which a long-held HTTP request allows a web server to push data to a browser, without the browser explicitly requesting it.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)

WebSocket is designed to be implemented in web browsers and web servers, but it can be used by any client or server application. The WebSocket Protocol is an independent TCP-based protocol. Its only relationship to HTTP is that its handshake is interpreted by HTTP servers as an Upgrade request.[1]

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_sockets

Azure "Platform As A Service" AWS "Infrastructure as a service"
http://gigaom.com/2011/09/04/the-great-debate-windows-azure-vs-amazon-web-services/

Good description of polling vs long polling vs ajax for streaming data
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh965663.aspx